# Add icon to the right side of a tab in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qicon

I don't manage to find a way to put an icon to the right side of a tab. By default, PyQt puts it to the left side. What is the code to change this ?

Here is what I have for the moment :

[image: The tabs]

The red cross is my icon but I don't manage to put it to the right side

Here is my code :

```
tab_index1 = self.tab_widget.addTab(self.tab, "Tab 1")
self.tab_widget.setTabIcon(tab_index1, QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))
```

And another problem I have is that the code inside the tab is cut because of the icon. Someone knows how to fix this ?